# unexpected end of file: elements not closed VB xmlreader: Parse?

Tags: xml, vb.net

So, this example comes right from MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasbase64.aspx
 Pretty much the only thing I have changed is created a loop because I have one xmlstring and want to break it up and create tif files from it(which it actually does do).

My problem is this: readbytes inside the while loop throws an exception at the last time through the loop that says I have an "unexpected end of file; the following elements are not closed" and lists them

```vb
   Public Shared Sub Base64DecodeImageFile() 

        Dim buffer(999) As Byte
         Dim readBytes As Integer = 0

        Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlstring)

                Dim outputFile As New FileStream("C:\artFiles\data\newImage.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
                ' Read to the image element.
                reader.ReadToFollowing("image")
                ' Read the Base64 data.
                Console.WriteLine(vbCr + vbLf + "Reading Base64...")
                Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(outputFile)
                readBytes = reader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, 50)
                While (readBytes > 0)
                    bw.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes)
                    readBytes = reader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, 50)
                End While
                outputFile.Close()

        End Using

    End Sub 'Base64DecodeImageFile
```

So there are tags left open after the readtofollowing("image").  I tried catching the exception to no avail, tried to read until eof, no avail.  I dont really need elements to be closed, I just need to continue because I created files using whats in the image tag.

I appreciate any help!

**EDIT**: I think my xmlstring is going to have times where it will be too big to do a parse without slowing down too much.../parsing binary data?

Comment: Maybe you don't need them to be closed, but you are using XML, and they need them to be closed ;) Can you just parse the XML before and check for integrity?

Comment: to be honest, xml is not my strong point. I wouldn't know how.. :(

Comment: then google and a lot of read are your friends ;).. if you are building the xml, check that you are building it ok..

Comment: yeah, im reading on it now.. would doing this slow down my program though?

Comment: No clue about that.. you will have to test it..

Comment: well thanks for the help but i hope there is another way around it.. i hope.

Comment: If you would provide the XML structure, it may be possible to tell whats going wrong

Comment: milter- it actually wouldn't have helped.. what was wrong was in the string itself ... see answer below :) thank you though milter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well!  I found out my issue..I figured I would post the answer anyway to maybe help some others?   the problem did not lay with the reader, in fact, it worked really well.  The problem was the xmlstring itself. The string never created the closing tags I needed (which would happen the last loop through).
Thanks for your help anyway guys!